# What is the name of the guitar accompaniment in this song?

Tags: guitar, learning, rhythm, accompaniment

I'm a beginner in guitar playing. I come across [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lGSl5FXQLDQ) type of accompaniment (specifically the rhythm on the right hand) frequently in songs and really like it but don't know what it's called to search for tutorials. Can I get help to point me in the right direction? Thanks.

Comment: do you mean the chords and how he works with the right hand or with the left?

Comment: What makes you think you need a tutorial? Have you _tried_ doing something similar? Slow down the video to 0.5x speed?

Comment: That's a valid point. I have tried to do that of course. It's faster to reach for the guitar than typing a question. But there are different variations far as I can see, so I think knowing what it is can help me get a bigger picture.

Comment: Try "fingerstyle slapping".

Answer (score 2):

There are a few things he's doing with the rhythm. I'm not sure if there's a name for the whole effect, though.

The *slaps* happen on beats 2 and 4, constituting a **backbeat**.

There's a chord on beat 1 and a staccato chord on the last 16th note of beat one. This is sometimes called an **anticipation**.

The bass thumps are on the last 2 16ths of beat 2, stopping just before beat 3 which would normally be the second strongest beat after beat 1. This could be considered a **syncopation**, having a rest where you would expect a note. You can kind of feel a beat here even though you don't hear anything.

Answer (score 2):

Did you look up *fingerstyle slapping* as piiperi suggests:

I‘found this video that teaches, how to master finger style slapping (10 exercises):

Answer (score 1):

If you mean the rhythmic accompaniment of the right hand:

*On certain beats, instead of a full strum of the strings, we mute all the strings with our strumming hand, and simply run the pick across the dead strings, creating a "blip" kind of sound. This sound creates a very pleasing rhythmic contrast to the rest of the strums, which carry a full tone. The key to its effectiveness is that it is creating an accent on the beat it falls on.*

It is called the **slap strum.**

https://www.guitarprinciples.com/guitar-principles-slap-strum/

But there may be different names like this link  shows:

https://goodguitarist.com/the-strum-slap-add-some-percussion-to-your-strumming/

Searching for "slap strum" you will find plenty of tutorials.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear in the question. I edited the question to specify the rhythm he uses, kind of making use of the percussive slap and bass note ornaments.